# Programmatic JMeter configuration with CSV test data

Tags: csv, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing

I'm running JMeter programmatically from Java code and I'd like to generate a bunch of POST requests with a varying body. 
Here is a sampler I use to generate one request:

```
HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
sampler.setDomain("localhost");
sampler.setPort(8081);
sampler.setPath("/service");
sampler.setMethod("POST");
sampler.addEncodedArgument("body", "{\"key\": \"data\"}");
sampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
```

How can I replace `data` in the body for each request with a value from a CSV file?

I know there is `CSV Data Set Config` plugin in GUI version but I haven't found a way to use it from Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're able to create the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) you can take the similar steps to create the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). Just look into .jmx file and convert what you see there into Java code.

Just in case if you are not able:

```
CSVDataSet csvDataSet = new CSVDataSet();
csvDataSet.setName("CSV Data Set Config");
csvDataSet.setProperty("delimiter", ",");
csvDataSet.setProperty("filename", "test.csv");
csvDataSet.setProperty("ignoreFirstLine", false);
csvDataSet.setProperty("quotedData", false);
csvDataSet.setProperty("recycle", true);
csvDataSet.setProperty("shareMode", "shareMode.all");
csvDataSet.setProperty("stopThread", false);
csvDataSet.setProperty("variableNames", "foo");
csvDataSet.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, csvDataSet.getClass().getName());
csvDataSet.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on various ways of kicking off a JMeter test including creating script from scratch in Java.

---

If your test plan generation has to be programmatic but doesn't have to be Java you may find [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool much easier to use as you will be able to create a test using declarative YAML syntax.